# How to print without spaces in python 3?

Tags: python

```
>>> income = 50
>>> print("Your income tax is $",income,".")
Your income tax is $ 50 .
```

So how do I print "$ 50 ." together?

Comment: Add this keyword arg to the print function `sep=''` or use `str.format()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sep` argument to print:

```
>>> income = 50000
>>> print("Your income tax is $", income, ".", sep='')
Your income tax is $50000.
```

Or use the `str.format`:

```
>>> print("Your income tax is ${}.".format(income))
Your income tax is $50000.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this:

```
x = 50
x = str(x)
y = 'Your Income is $'
z='.'
print(y+x+z)
```

Output:
Your Income is $50.

Answer (score 0):

Use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
print("Your income tax is ${0}.".format(income))
```