# How to prevent spaces occuring when printing values

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I use this line of code, spaces occur around the letter 'e', which I am trying to avoid. Even though this isn't a major problem in the code, it will just help to make it read better.

I have tried to reshuffle the layout of my code but there has been no success

```
print("The value of", '\033[1m', '\033[4m', "e", '\033[0m', "is", math.e)
```

The output is

```
The value of  e  is 2.718281828459045
```

But I would much prefer the result to be

```
The value of e is 2.718281828459045
```

(Has only 1 space around 'e')

(Please note that the letter 'e' is bold and underlined in the output so that is working correctly.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without spaces in python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528767/how-to-print-without-spaces-in-python-3)

Comment: does this statement `print("The value of","e", "is",math.e)` is not giving you the expected output

Comment: @Deadpool that does not work because of the escape sequences they are using in their print statements.

Comment: i'm just wondering either he only need `e` and `math.e` or he need all of the parameters? @blackbrandt

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @Deadpool the terms that look like `\033[1m` are used to make the output bold and underlined. In a python terminal, paste his output vs your output and see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3).

```
import math
print("The value of {} is {}".format("e", math.e)
```

If you want to include the bold and underlining:

```
import math
print("The value of {}{}{}{} is {}".format('\033[1m', '\033[4m', "e", '\033[0m',  math.e))
```

Comment: Should really be: `{}{}{}{} is {}` instead of `{} {} {} {} is {}`

Comment: Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid `print()` printing a space between its arguments, use the `sep` keyword:

```py
print('No', 'Space', '!', sep='')
```

which prints:

> NoSpace!

However, for printing that string, it may be beneficial to use the `f` qualifier for string interpolation (requires Python 3.6+) and a library for ANSI escaping, e.g. [`blessed`](https://pypi.org/project/blessed/):

```py
import math
import blessed

t = blessed.Terminal()

import math
print(f"The value of {t.bold}{t.underline}e{t.normal} is {math.e}")
```

For earlier versions of Python, you could use the `.format(**locals())` construct, which is (almost) equivalent to the `f` string interpolation:

```py
import math
import blessed

t = blessed.Terminal()

import math

print("The value of {t.bold}{t.underline}e{t.normal} is {math.e}".format(**locals()))
```

(*EDIT: added a bit more explanation*).

Answer (score 1):

No need to use string formatting and import blessed. Try this:

> '\033[0m' = ResetAll
>
> '\033[1m' = Bold
>
> '\033[4m' = Underline

```
print ("The value of" + '\033[1m', '\033[4m' + "e" + '\033[0m',"is",math.e)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Of course it is not **needed**, but it is a much better framework to use! By the same logic, there is no need to use Python, you might as well write your own assembly...

Comment: There can be many solutions to this by using x formatting or y import but making the approach of the person work with min changes to his code is what I think he looks for. I guess.

Comment: I thought the goal would be teach/learn best coding practices, but I guess not everybody is after that. Of course, if the metric is the character difference from OP code, then this approach fares better.

Comment: You are absolutely right master I totally agree with you but don't know why people prefer this way, Maybe because of hurry in solving the issue at the time.